# Explain why series divergent or convergent

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

See question title.

The series is as follows:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty{2n+\sin{n}\over {e^n-\cos n}}$$

Now, common sense dictates that the numerator "goes to infinity" much slower than the denominator, therefore the series is convergent. How to show this in more formal terms?

Thanks in advance for any and all advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use \begin{align}\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{{2(n+1)+\sin{(n+1)}\over {e^{n+1}-\cos (n+1)}}}{2n+\sin{n}\over {e^n-\cos n}}\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{2(n+1)+\sin{(n+1)}}{2n+\sin{n}}\times\frac{e^{n}-\cos n}{e^{n+1}-\cos (n+1)}\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{2n(1+\frac{1}{n}+\frac{\sin{(n+1)}}{2n})}{2n(1+\frac{\sin{n}}{2n})}\times\frac{e^{n}(1-\frac{\cos n}{e^n})}{e^{n+1}(1-\frac{\cos (n+1)}{e^{n+1}})}\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(1+\frac{1}{n}+\frac{\sin{(n+1)}}{2n})}{(1+\frac{\sin{n}}{2n})}\times\frac{(1-\frac{\cos n}{e^n})}{e(1-\frac{\cos (n+1)}{e^{n+1}})}\\
&=\color{red}{\frac{(1+0+0)}{(1+0)}\times\frac{(1-0)}{e(1-0)}}\\
&=\frac{1}{e}
\end{align}

Note that since $-1\leq \sin x\leq 1, -1\leq \cos x\leq 1\Rightarrow \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\cos n}{e^{n}}=0~\text{and}~\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sin n}{n}=0$

Comment: Perfect. Why $1\over e$ though?

Comment: let me elaborate a bit more

Comment: I updated it, if you had any question just ask

Comment: $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\cos n}{e^{n}}=0$

Is this a theorem of some kind? I know about the other one.

Comment: Is it because $\lim_{n\to\infty}{1 \over e^n}=0$ ?

Comment: $ -1\leq \cos x\leq 1\Rightarrow \color{green}{0}= \lim_{n\to\infty}  \frac{ -1}{e^n}\leq \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\cos n}{e^{n}}\leq\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{e^n}=\color{green}{0}$

Comment: What about my version?

Comment: yours it correst, too. since $\lim\frac{1}{e^n}=0$ and $\cos n$ is bounded you will get $\frac{1}{e^n}\cos n\to 0$

Answer (score 1):

We have $$\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{2n+\sin\left(n\right)}{e^{n}-\cos\left(n\right)}\leq\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{2n+1}{e^{n}-1}\sim\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{2n}{e^{n}}=\frac{2e}{\left(e-1\right)^{2}}.$$

Comment: Can you explain your reasoning please?

Comment: @fresh_jim In the first inequality I only use the fact that $-1 \leq \cos(x),\, \sin(x) \leq1$, in the second passage I use the fact that the two series have the same behavior at $n\rightarrow \infty$ and the last series can be calculated using the geometric series identity.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to compare the terms to
$$
\frac{1}{2^n}
$$
or something else that is clearly larger (for $n\geq10$, at least) and just as clearly converges.

Comment: Why ${1\over{2^n}}$ ?

Comment: @fresh_jim Because $1$ is not much smaller than $2n+\sin n$, while $2^n$ is much smaller than $e^n$. I could've used $\frac{3n}{2^n}$ instead, and the comparing would be easier, but the convergence would be a smidgen more difficult.